# Как в Python перехватить системное событие MouseClick?

Tags: python, windows

Возможно, не совсем ясно выразился. Стоит задача определения места (координат) клика по окну (отдельное приложение). Координаты определяю с помощью win32api.GetCursorPos().

Comment: Вы имеете в виду клик по любому чужому окну?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через функцию winapi WindowFromPoint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558(v=vs.85).aspx

Этой функции нет в модуле win32api, поэтому придется похоже написать на С или на Cython свой модуль, в котором сделать обертку для этой функции.

Answer (score 1):

Сам натолкнулся на замечательный проект pyHook

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page

Правда возникли небольшие проблемки с компиляцией, но все решаемо!

Пример работы:

MessageName: mouse right down

Message: 516

Time: 8590562

Window: 1312060

WindowName: C:Python26python.exe

Position: (408, 227)

Wheel: 0

Injected: 0

MessageName: key down

Message: 256

Time: 8591406

Window: 1312060

WindowName: C:Python26python.exe

Ascii: 27 <

Key: Escape

KeyID: 27

ScanCode: 1

Extended: 0

Injected: 0

Alt 0

Transition 0